# How can I set HTTP status code in hyper HTTP Server handler?

Tags: rust, hyper

According to the [documentation](https://hyperium.github.io/hyper/hyper/server/response/struct.Response.html) I could get mutable reference to the `status` by calling `status_mut()`. Unfortunately signature of the handler function, used to serve requests with hyper::Server contain immutable `Response`, so the following code gives me an error:

```
pub fn handle_request(req: Request, res: Response<Fresh>){
    let status: &mut StatusCode = res.status_mut();
}

error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `res` as mutable
```

Is there any way to set response status code in the request handler, used by hyper::server::Server?

**UPD**: Finally I have found the example. Right in the [source code](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/server.rs). =*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutability in Rust is inherited, so you can just mark the parameter as mutable to get mutability:

```
pub fn handle_request(req: Request, mut res: Response<Fresh>){
    let status: &mut StatusCode = res.status_mut();
}
```

This is possible because this function accepts `Response<Fresh>` by value - if it accepted it by reference: `&Response<Fresh>`, it would be impossible to modify it at all.

Comment: Thanks. But There is another problem - res bocme borrowed, when I call status_mut(), so I can't use res after this call. I simply try to answer with Response(StatusCode::Forbidden, "Auth failed") in the handler...

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do, but there is a universal method when you want to limit borrow boundaries - take the code which creates and uses a borrow in curly braces: `{ let status = res.status_mut(); status.whatever(...); } /* here res is available again */`.